# Design Pattern for complicated queries

Tags: python, sql, design-patterns

We are currently developing an application that makes heavy use of PostgreSQL. For the most part we access the database using SQLAlchemy, and this works very well. For testing the relevant objects can be either mocked, or used without database access. But there are some parts of the system that run non-standard queries. These subsystems have to create temporary tables insert a huge number of rows and then merge data back into the main table.

Currently there are some SQL statements in these subsystems, but this makes the relevant classes tightly coupled with the database, which in turn makes things harder to unit-test.

Basically my question is, is there any design pattern for solving this problem? The only thing that I could come up with is to put these SQL statements into a separate class and just pass an instance to the other class. This way I can mock the *query-class* for unit-tests, but it still feels a bit clumsy. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around with it some more I now have a solution that is halfway decent. I split the class in question up into three separate classes:

- A class that provides access to the required data;
- A context manager that supports the temporary table stuff;
- And the old class with all the logic (sans the database stuff);

When I instantiate my logic class I supply it with an instance of the aforementioned classes. It works ok, abstraction is slightly leaky (especially the context manager), but I can at least unit test the logic properly now.